# how to connect liberty - webshere with sqlite database deployed locally?

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, websphere-liberty

Spring applciation build in war by maven.
I deploy localy liberty websphere and configured sqlite

When try to use liberty+oracle - there is no problems, but when try to use liberty+sqlite, there is error message with fail connection to database

there is my server.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <!-- database connection -->
  <library id="SQLiteLib">
    <fileset dir="C:\servers\wlp-webProfile8-20.0.0.1\lib" includes="sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar" />
  </library>

  <jdbcDriver id="SQLiteDriver" libraryRef="SQLiteLib" javax.sql.DataSource="org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource" javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.sqlite.javax.SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource" />

  <dataSource id="InventoryDataSource" jdbcDriverRef="SQLiteDriver" jndiName="jdbc/MYDATASOURCE" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <properties URL="jdbc:sqlite:C:\servers\wlp-webProfile8-20.0.0.1\sqlite\sqlite3\student.db" />
  </dataSource>



  <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" />
  <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
  <applicationManager autoExpand="true" updateTrigger="mbean" />
  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
  <application id="MyApp" location="C:\workspace\sb_merger_before\sb\MyApp-webapp\target\MyApp" name="MyApp" type="war" />
  <application id="MyApp_webapp_war_exploded" location="C:\workspace\sb_merger_before\sb\MyApp-webapp\target\MyApp" name="MyApp_webapp_war_exploded" type="war" />
</server>
```

So, with this server configuration there is error connection with datasouce and database

I got this exampe [here](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005phqvKCAQ/how-to-set-up-the-sqlitejdbc-driver-as-a-jdbcdriver-datasource-on-liberty-when-sqlitejdbc-doesnt-support-connectiongettypemap-?language=en_US) but it can't help with connection.

error message listing in idea logs

> [2020-02-14 18:16:20.788] WARN 
>   rnate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
>   [2020-02-14 18:16:20.788] ERROR
>   rnate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper not yet implemented
>   DSRA0010E: Состояние SQL = null, Код ошибки = 0 [2020-02-14
>   18:16:20.792] WARN  rnate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper SQL
>   Error: 0, SQLState: null [2020-02-14 18:16:20.792] ERROR
>   rnate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper not yet implemented
>   DSRA0010E: Состояние SQL = null, Код ошибки = 0 [2020-02-14
>   18:16:20.793] ERROR .services.data.service.DiagnosticService при
>   попытке соединения с бд возникла ошибка: Could not open JPA
>   EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection

Comment: can you include the error you are seeing in your question? Without the full error it's hard to say. Also, check out this blog post for testing DB connections with liberty: https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/09/13/testing-database-connections-REST-APIs.html

Comment: @AndyGuibert updated, 
may be error message cauesed <property> in datasouce? For oracle this property has different name.

Comment: it looks like it may be a compatibility issue with Hibernate because of "RROR rnate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper not yet implemented".
Try the test connection procedure in the blog I linked previously -- that will test the JDBC connection directly (and take Hibernate out of the equation)

Comment: also, try changing `<properties URL="..."/>` to be `<properties url="..."/>` with the `url` property lowercase instead of uppercase. According to the SQLite code their url property is lowercase: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/SQLiteDataSource.java#L86
It is `setUrl` instead of `setURL`

Comment: @AndyGuibert there is one more difference with working example of oracle database is that, doesn't created HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE table in sqlite database. I think this is critical